# React Native Navigation Gesture

Tags: ios, react-native

I am using React Native's `Navigator` to navigate through scenes in iOS app. I found that although I can swipe back to previous screen by swiping from left edge to right, it looks like the region that I can swipe is not as big or responsive as the native navigation. Sometimes I swipe a little off the edge and it doesn't work.

I am wondering if there is a way to apply some tuning to this area, i.e. make the swipe go back area a little bigger so user have better success rate.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best solution but you can change the edgeHitWidth in NavigatorSceneConfigs.js

The default for 'left-to-right' is 30

This will affect your entire project and every time you upgrade react native you will need to make these changes again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it still can help but :

```
const SCREEN_WIDTH = require('Dimensions').get('window').width;

const buildStyleInterpolator = require('buildStyleInterpolator');

const BaseSceneConfig = Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump;
const CustomBackGesture = Object.assign({}, BaseSceneConfig.gestures.jumpBack, {
  // Make it so we can drag anywhere on the screen
  edgeHitWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH,

});
const CustomForwardGesture = Object.assign({}, BaseSceneConfig.gestures.jumpForward, {
  // Make it so we can drag anywhere on the screen
  edgeHitWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH,

});
const CustomSceneConfig = Object.assign({}, BaseSceneConfig, {
  // A very tighly wound spring will make this transition fast
  springTension: 100,
  springFriction: 1,
  gestures: {
    jumpBack: CustomBackGesture,
    jumpForward: CustomForwardGesture,
  },
});
```

you can customize gesture and edgeHitWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH does the trick.