# How can I swipe full screen/card to get next/previous screen/card in react-native without using any library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Please note that I have been through questions like these and none match with the criteria that I have in mind and most of the answers ask you to use a library.

I want to build an animation for the screen/card exactly like this for pratice purposes in React Native: [Inshorts](https://www.inshorts.com/)

I am adding the video of the animation I am trying to achieve for people who do not want to install the app:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-lvrU34Jt50

So, if you have installed this app, you can observe that one can swipe the card up to read the **next news** or swipe down to read the **previous news**.

While swiping the card half-way, you can slightly see the content of the card stacked right beneath the card being swiped up. And the same happens when you swipe down.

I know that this is panning but what I am really confused about is how can one achieve this in React Native?

Like should I do it using Navigator or there is no need to use a Navigator?

Or should I stack cards using absolute position?

I am not after the code. All I need to know is what should be the approach
to achieve it?

Flipping a card up and getting the other one shouldn't be a problem. But, how can I give a glimpse of the next card in the stack while the user has just started to pan the current card upwards.

**PLEASE NOTE:** I do not want to do this using a React Native library.

Comment: I am also trying to achieve the same and open to third-party libraries. Did you able to come up with solution?

Comment: I am facing the same problem, any help? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can do this without `Navigator` by implementing the pan handling yourself. But then you also need to implement the pushing and popping views off of the stack as well.
2. You get the majority of this functionality out of box by using `Navigator` which ships with React Native. 
   I would suggest you look into creating a custom [Navigator Scene Config](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/f64538943e180adc2180d89285fab6727eaf3982/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/NavigatorSceneConfigs.js) and a custom gesture for pushing and popping the views off the navigator stack. Here's an example of how another user made the whole view draggable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40471281/1883144